# Get var from Other file in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I get 3 files, I want to use the variable values from each other, one file is :

```
public class Dialogs
{
    public Dictionary<string, Phrase> Phrases = new Dictionary<string, Phrase>();

}
public class Phrase
{
    public string PhraseID = null;
    public string Role = null;
}
```

the second one goes here:

```
public class DiaLoader
{
        public Dialogs LoadDialog()
    {
        // Variables
        List<Phrase> phrasesList = new List<Phrase>();
        Dialogs resultDialog = new Dialogs();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="1"></Phrase>
        <Phrase  Role="2"></Phrase>");
    //get all the phrases
        XmlNodeList phrases = xml.GetElementsByTagName("Phrase");
            foreach (XmlNode phraseNode in phrases)
            {
                Phrase phrase = NodeToPhrase(phraseNode);
                phrasesList.Add(phrase);
            }
    //Phrase node to phrase
        private Phrase NodeToPhrase(XmlNode node)
        {
            Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
            XmlNode roleNode = node.Attributes["Role"];
            if (roleNode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleNode.Value))
                phrase.Role = roleNode.Value;

            return phrase;
        }  
}
```

as you can see, i give the the string Role value using xml in the second file,, and the third one, I want to create var and get the value of Role, how can I do it? My code goes here:

```
    DiaLoader dia= new DiaLoader();
    public void Export(dia.LoadDialog()) {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    string myVar = Phrase.Role;//this can't the value of role
  }
```

Comment: That's not valid XML. There must be only one root node.

Comment: And where is the variable `xml` defined?

Comment: Your question as it currently is, is unclear, and your code seems incomplete and will certainly not compile as is: (1) you are not setting the `PhraseID` property for a `Phrase`, and it is unclear where this values should come from. (2) your `LoadDialog` method is supposed to return a `Dialogs` instance and doesn't. (3) what would the `key` be for the `Phrases` dictionary member of the `Dialogs` class?

Comment: Well, because i cut out some pieces of my code, so the first 2 file are not good,,maybe assume that the dictionary Phrase.Role.Value ={"2","1","1","2","1","2"}, I want to create a var in the third file,,how should do that,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your example you have some phrases in a xml file, something like:

```
<Phrases>
    <Phrase Role="2">Example 1</Phrase>
    <Phrase Role="2">Example 2</Phrase>
    <Phrase Role="1">Example 3</Phrase>
    <Phrase Role="1">Example 4</Phrase>
    <Phrase Role="2">Example 5</Phrase>
    <Phrase Role="1">Example 6</Phrase>
    <Phrase Role="2">Example 7</Phrase>
</Phrases>
```

And you want to read all these phrases into a dictionary, and later retrieve the text for certain role.

So, I modified a bit your code to allow to compile.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test001
{
    public class Dialogs
    {
        private static string DEFAULT_DATA =
            "<Phrases>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"2\">Example 1</Phrase>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"2\">Example 2</Phrase>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"1\">Example 3</Phrase>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"1\">Example 4</Phrase>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"2\">Example 5</Phrase>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"1\">Example 6</Phrase>" +
                "<Phrase Role=\"2\">Example 7</Phrase>" +
            "</Phrases>"
        ;

        private int nextID;

        private Dictionary<string, Phrase> Phrases = new Dictionary<string, Phrase>();

        public List<Phrase> PhrasesList
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Phrases.Values.ToList();
            }
        }


        public Dialogs()
        {
            this.Phrases = new Dictionary<string, Phrase>();
            this.nextID = 0;
        }

        public bool Load(string filename = null)
        {
            this.Phrases.Clear();
            this.nextID = 0;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                if (filename == null)
                {
                    doc.LoadXml(DEFAULT_DATA);
                }
                else
                {
                    doc.Load(filename);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Error loading data
                return false;
            }

            // Get all the phrases
            XmlNodeList phrases = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Phrase");
            foreach (XmlNode phraseNode in phrases)
            {
                Phrase phrase = NodeToPhrase(phraseNode);
                this.Add(phrase);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void Add(Phrase phrase)
        {
            this.Phrases.Add(this.nextID.ToString(), phrase);
            this.nextID++;
        }

        // Parse a xml node to a phrase
        private Phrase NodeToPhrase(XmlNode node)
        {
            Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
            XmlNode roleNode = node.Attributes["Role"];
            if (roleNode != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleNode.Value))
            {
                phrase.Role = roleNode.Value;
                phrase.PhraseID = this.nextID.ToString();
                if (node.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    phrase.Text = node.FirstChild.Value;
                }
                this.nextID++;
            }

            return phrase;
        }
    }
}
```

I left unchanged the class Phrase, except added a new field to store the text

```
public class Phrase
{
    public string PhraseID = null;
    public string Role = null;
    public string Text = null;
}
```

And for the usage, it would be something like this:

```
Dialogs dia = new Dialogs();
// dia.Load("full_path_to_your_nice_xml_file.xml")
dia.Load();     // Load default xml data just for testing purposes
var myVar = dia.PhrasesList.Find(phrase => phrase.Role == "2").Text;
```